# Restlet: Retrieving http body in verifier

Tags: java, api, rest, post, restlet

When I want retrieve the http body of a post in my Request Verifier it kinda resets my entity and I get a nullpointer exception when I want to get the http body in my resource class.

**Verifier**:

```
JsonRepresentation jsonrep;
        try {
            Representation entity = request.getEntity();
            jsonrep = new JsonRepresentation(entity);
            //bug: entity resets when getJsonObject is being called.
            JSONObject jsonobj = jsonrep.getJsonObject();
            if(companyId != jsonobj.getInt("id_companies")){
                return Verifier.RESULT_INVALID;
            }
...
```

**AppResource**:

```
@Post
public Representation addApp(Representation rep) throws Exception{
//rep is null
    JsonRepresentation jsonrep = new JsonRepresentation(rep);
```

When I dont't call:

```
                JSONObject jsonobj = jsonrep.getJsonObject();
```

it  just works fine.

Is anybody facing the same issue or got a solution for it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, by default, the representation is an InputRepresentation that doesn't store the representation content.

In your case, the simplest way is to wrap the representation into a StringRepresentation within your verifier:

```
Representation entity = request.getEntity();
StringRepresentation sEntity = new StringRepresentation(entity);
request.setEntity(sEntity);

JsonRepresentation jsonrep = new JsonRepresentation(sEntity);
```

Then, the string representation will be automatically provided to your server resource method...

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Comment: Yay! It works for me. However I needed to change one line: StringRepresentation sEntity = new StringRepresentation(entity.getText());
Thanks for your help!